# How to set the c:/fakepath of file in javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to upload a file using js (for testing purpose). Since I couldn't able to set the `val` of `type=file` of the `input` element this is what I have done.

1. Changed the type to `hidden`.
2. Set the value of the `input` now. Its getting set.
3. Now calls the upload button.

The problem is everything is working fine, expect the last 3rd step. If we upload manually browser sets the path like this:

```
C:\fakepath\ourfile_name.txt
```

Now I want to do the same thing, but I'm not sure, how the:

```
C:\fakepath\ourfile_name.txt
```

is getting converted to the the real path I have given when I upload manually:

```
/users/test/Downloads/ourfile_name.txt
```

Somehow the browser is resolving that, when the upload is being clicked. I want to know, how should I do that?

Any idea will be real help here.

Comment: For security reasons , you can't get the `local directory path` from client-side .That has to be done at server side .

Comment: When you upload a file, yo get the properties server-side. Including the temp path of the uploaded file.

Comment: @Alfabravo: How to do that?

Comment: Thing is: We haven't seen your code but so far, I think you are just producing a file submit form with JS. The problem is: you are just submitting it to a different page of your site to handle it. It's there where you will get the upload info; JS is sending a HTTP POST message with the file. Show some code to give further help.